# Making matrix in R

Tags: r

I want to make matrices without using loops such as for , while.
So I tried assigned k and put k in function which makes matrices.

```
powlist= function(base,startnum,endnum) (base)^(startnum:endnum)

m_maker= function(base) matrix(c(powlist(base,0,19)),4,5)

k= 2:10
a= m_maker((k-1)/k)
```

But function returns only one matrix.
I think function should return 9 matrices.
Please let me know how should I change this code.

I want to make each matrices that first one is matrix `m_maker(1/2)` and
second one `m_maker(2/3)` so on.
When I put `k=2` and `k=3` each time, it returns what I want.
What I want is way to return 9 matrices at one to go.

Comment: Please show your desired output (as an R object we can read into R). It may be necessary to reduce the size of your example. By the way, your `m_maker` function does not work for any input, so you might want to examine that before trying to use it like this.

Comment: One of your problems is that the matrix in `m_maker` does not fit.  Try `m_maker(1/2)` to give a 20x20 matrix and `c(powlist(1/2, 0, 20))` to give a 21 element vector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for `lapply`, like

```
res <- lapply((k-1)/k, m_maker)
```

However, you really should use an array for something like this.

```
ares <- abind(res, along=3)
```

Comment: I want to make each matrices that first one is matrix m_maker(1/2) and second one m_maker(2/3) so on. When I put k=2 and k=3 each time, it returns what I want. What I want is way to return nine matrices at one to go.